# Running into error while starting se.plan tool

Tags: sepal

I am a new user and I am exploring the se.plan tool. I am connected to my Google account and have signed up to Google Earth Engine. At the very beginning when trying to load se.plan I ran in to this error:

> There was an error when executing cell [1]. Please run Voilà with
> --show_tracebacks=True or --debug to see the error message, or configure VoilaConfiguration.show_tracebacks.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Application in the SEPAL platform are running voila kernels. The error displayed here is telling you that the cell 1 was not executing itself properly.

Based on the date of your issue, I think you were caught in the roll out of a new version.

In the notification system the following message have been send to all users on 2021-12-09:

> Yesterday a new version of SEPAL was deployed and some users may have experienced difficulties accessing applications. The situation is back to normal and every application is again available. We are sorry for any inconvenience this issue caused.

If the error persists on you system I think you should consider contacting the development team of the app directly on their GitHub repository: https://github.com/12rambau/restoration_planning_module/issues